# Can I create a t4 file with user input?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, templates, t4

I am trying to make a generator for cs files through commandline. I want to use T4 because I'm not really aware of another way to generate files and move them easily. The problem I'm having is trying to pass user input data to the T4 Files.

For Example the user in my program would input their name

`Bob`

My T4 template I want the output to be

`Hello Bob`

I can't seem to pass data to it unless I wrote it to a text file and read it from it. Is there another way that I could do this? At some point I need it to handle collections of attributes which could be a pain to read properly in a text file.

Comment: Didn't you run `texttransform /?` to see what command line arguments are available?  Did you not see anything about passing in variables and values via the command line?  Are we not men?  Is there but one Lincoln?  Random question intensifies?

Comment: I'm actually building the entire project in C# so I'm not using texttransform

Comment: https://github.com/scy0846/NetOnJets

Comment: I'm hoping to do everything through the app and not rely on external applications

Comment: That would probably be good info to include in an [edit]...  T4 templates *do* have a concept of an "environment", the standard one being EnvDTE... I'm sure there's a way to hook in through that, passing in your own "environment" via which you can supply variables and values (i.e., instead of VS passing EnvDTE into the T4 engine as the "environment", create your own and pass *that* in...)

Comment: Ah ok. I might just end up finding another way to template that then. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a [T4 parameter directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586944.aspx) you can pass values from the app domain into your T4 template.

Create a parameter:

```
<#@ parameter type="Full.TypeName" name="ParameterName" #>
```

Put it in your template:

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.String" name="MyUserName" #>
<# Console.Write(MyUserName) #>
```

Populate it from code:

```
// Get a service provider – how you do this depends on the context:
IServiceProvider serviceProvider = dte; // or dslDiagram.Store, for example 
// Get the text template service:
ITextTemplating t4 = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(STextTemplating)) 
                                                     as ITextTemplating;
ITextTemplatingSessionHost host = t4 as ITextTemplatingSessionHost;
// Create a Session in which to pass parameters:
host.Session = host.CreateSession();
// Add parameter values to the Session:
session["MyUserName"] = "Bob";
// Process a text template:
string result = t4.ProcessTemplate("MyTemplateFile.t4",
                                    System.IO.File.ReadAllText("MyTemplateFile.t4"));
```

[Another helpful link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/92669a0b-cb8c-413d-b984-e031f96eb3c7/running-t4-template-through-code-and-passing-parametrs-at-runtime-?forum=vsx)